# gocql - using Cassandra 3 timeuuid functions

Tags: gocql

In cqlsh I can execute something like:

```
SELECT id FROM names WHERE name = 'dave' AND id > maxTimeuuid('2015-04-05 00:05') AND id < minTimeuuid('2019-01-01 00:05');
```

... this returns a list as expected.

```
 id
--------------------------------------
 632f4960-375b-11e8-90b1-02420a000203
 91f03523-3761-11e8-a777-02420a000a05
 32dbffc4-3762-11e8-a778-02420a000a05
 9ffb1ab8-3762-11e8-a779-02420a000a05
 c28a0372-3764-11e8-a77b-02420a000a05
```

However I am struggling to get this to work in gocql:

```
var found bool = false
m := map[string]interface{}{}
qString := "SELECT id FROM names WHERE name=? AND id > maxTimeuuid(?) AND id < minTimeuuid(?);"
query := Cassandra.Sessionds.Query(qString, name, toFrom.From, toFrom.To).Consistency(gocql.One)
fmt.Println("sending IsRunning query: " + query.String())
iterable := query.Iter()
for iterable.MapScan(m) {
    found = true
    lookupTable = HostLookup {
        Id:     m["id"].(gocql.UUID),
    }
}
```

Even though the debug line looks ok,

```
sending IsRunning query: [query statement="SELECT id FROM names WHERE name=? AND id > maxTimeuuid(?) AND id < minTimeuuid(?);" values=[dave 2015-04-05 00:05 2019-01-01 00:05] consistency=ONE]
```

... I always end up with an empty iterable. I am using very similar code elsewhere successfully, the difference here are the timeuuid functions. I've tried various arrangements with literal quotes to no avail, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I looked at the iterable in more detail I found :

"can not marshal string into timestamp"

... this led me to the answer - [GoCQL : Marshal string into timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640544/gocql-marshal-string-into-timestamp)